# In Julia, how to combine CSV file in given folder

Tags: dataframe, csv, julia

In Julia, here are tow questions:

1. how to fid files list in folder `D:\\working` ?
   the files include  `"result_1.csv","result_2.csv"，"result_3.csv"，"result_4.csv"`
2. after using `CSV.File` to combine CSV file, the class is `vector`. how to union them into a big
   DataFrame?

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
pwd()
cd("D:\\working\\logistics\\logistics_bill\\V5")
total = CSV.File.(["result_1月.csv","result_2月.csv"]).|>DataFrame
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To get the list of files in a directory use the [`readdir`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.readdir) function. Then you can filter this list to keep only the files that match your needs. Alternatively you can use [Glob.jl](https://github.com/vtjnash/Glob.jl)
2. To combine data frames use [`reduce`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Base.reduce) using [`vcat`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Base.vcat) the data frames:

```
reduce(vcat, CSV.read.(["result_1月.csv","result_2月.csv"]))
```

(you might want to pass some keyword arguments if you want more fancy merging, like making a union of columns incase the CSV files do not have the same schema)

Comment: 1.for question 1   'filter(contains("result"),readdir())' can get what I want ,it seems 'readdir(pattern='result')'   can't work ?    2. This is greate , is vcat can work for the files have no same columns ? (just like R/dplyr  'bind_rows()' )

Comment: Ad 1. - for pattern matching use Grep.jl as I have commended in the answer. Ad 2. - again, as I have commented it is possible, use the `cols=:union` value of the keyword argument for this case (but there are many more options - please check the linked documentation).